# Auto-ban IP from "wp-login.php" attackers

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, ip, brute-force-attacks

When I look at my Apache log `other_vhosts_access.log`, I see many many attempts, from a few different IP per month like this:

```
www.example.com:80 91.200.x.x - - [25/Jun/2017:17:20:19 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 
www.example.com:80 91.200.x.x - - [25/Jun/2017:17:20:19 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 
www.example.com:80 91.200.x.x - - [25/Jun/2017:17:20:20 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1"
```

It seems to be brute-force attacks.

**Is there a simple way to auto-ban** (no link with [Autobahn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gChOifUJZMc))  **these attackers?**

- If I do it with a Wordpress plugin, the traffic will still go into PHP, wasting resources, etc.
- If I do it at Apache level, it will surely still waste resource
- Should I do it at lowest level possible? i.e. IP tables?

Is there a tool that looks for such attackers in `other_vhosts_access.log` and automatically ban them in `iptables`?

Answer (score 3):

I finally just found a solution (I'll see if it works in a few days): fail2ban.

Let's put this in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`:

```
#
# HTTP servers
#

[apache-wp-login]
enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-wp-login
logpath = /var/log/apache2/other*.log
maxretry = 6
findtime = 36000
bantime = 36000
```

Then this in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-wp-login.conf`:

```
[Definition]
failregex = .*:(80|443) <HOST> .*/wp-login.php.*
ignoreregex =
```

Then let's start the service and look at the bans:

```
service fail2ban start
tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log
```

---

Very useful: this can help to debug the filtering regex and see if it works or not:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-wp-login.conf
```

Comment: For virtualmin I have changed jail to have logpath /var/log/virtualmin/*access_log and I have changed filter to be like: failregex = ^<HOST>.*/wp-login.php.*